# One layout works but other doesnt

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

everyone. I was creating a simple app for fun and came up with this problem. Basically, I checked everything and found some problem with the layouts. I am using navigation and from navigation, it takes the user to 4 different parts. Everything works except for the last part, the button is not taking me to anywhere.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

           DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)    
findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,   
R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)    
findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is    
present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



private void displaySelectedScreen(int id)
{
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch(id){
        case R.id.syllabus:
            fragment = new Syllabus();
            break;
        case R.id.questionss:
            fragment = new Questions();
            break;
        case R.id.definitions:
            fragment = new Definitions();
            break;
        case R.id.contact_us:
            fragment = new Contact_Us();
            break;
    }

    if(fragment != null){

        FragmentTransaction ft =    
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.list_content,fragment).addToBackStack("tag");
        ft.commit();
    }




}

public void chaptersdefinitions(View view) {
    Fragment newfragment = null;
    if (view == findViewById(R.id.chap1def)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter1def();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chap2def)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter2def();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chap3def)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter3def();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chap4def)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter4def();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chap5def)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter5def();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chap6def)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter6def();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chap7def)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter7def();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chap8def)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter8def();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chap9def)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter9def();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chap10def)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter10def();

    }  else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chapone)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter1();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chaptwo)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter2();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chapthree)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter3();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chapfour)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter4();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chapfive)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter5();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chapsix)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter6();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chapseven)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter7();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chapeight)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter8();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chapnine)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter9();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.chapten)) {
        newfragment = new Chapter10();
    }
    if (newfragment != null) {

        FragmentTransaction ft =      
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.list_content,      
newfragment).addToBackStack("tag");
            ft.commit();

        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)               
findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        displaySelectedScreen(id);
        return true;
    }
}
```

My content_main is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.weebly.dunyaibdp.chemistryforib.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_content"
    android:layout_width="451dp"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.885"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.493">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Hey There!"
        android:textColor="#64dd17"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.237" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Welcome to our Chemistry App"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.413"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.483" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="Use navigation on the left to navigate through app"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.558"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.53" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In navigation i have syllabus class which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollSyllabus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/chapone"
                android:layout_width="340sp"
                android:layout_height="70sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundshapebtn"
                android:onClick="chaptersdefinitions"
                android:text="@string/stoichometric_relations1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />


        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then my class for syllabus  is for layout is:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class Chapter1 extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup    
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.chapteronesyll,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("Stoichometric Relations");
}
}
```

With this class i use this layout to show:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="one" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now for this button i havent put any onclick so i just want this button to be displayed in screen and thats it. I tried some other layouts in my activity and some of them worked perfectly but some didnt i tried to delete and add again but this didnt work it still didnt print anything on the screen. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am very sorry everyone it was my (stupidity) i guess. When i run app on my phone the button was on the action bar and i couldnt see it. I put the text in the middle and everything was perfectly fine. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I suggest you delete the question altogether